# Auto Layout UIView on constraint change does not animate iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I'm trying to animate a view from "bottom-up" using AutoLayout.

This works great in iOS 8, however, it doesn't animate in iOS 7.

Here is a code snippet:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong) AViewController *aVC;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.aVC = [[AViewController alloc] init];
    self.aVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.aVC.view];
    [self.aVC.view autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeLeft withInset:0];
    [self.aVC.view autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight    toSize:100];
    [self.aVC.view autoSetDimension:ALDimensionWidth     toSize:320];
     NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [self.aVC.view autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge:ALEdgeBottom withInset:-100];
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        constraint.constant = -25;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];

}
```

I'm using the great [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) category, to add constraints easily.

Attaching [project sample on Github](https://github.com/justme1/autoLayout) - will work on iOS 8 simulator, and not iOS 7 simulator.

Any suggestions on how to make this work on iOS 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` with `[self.aVC.view layoutIfNeeded]`, it would work on both iOS versions. I don't know the specific reason though.

Edit.

Please try something like this.

```
[self.aVC.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
    constraint.constant = -25;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Please see my updated question; It not working with a xib that has subviews in it.

Comment: I download the old one, it worked for me. Did you modified anything in the xib?

Comment: Yes it did worked in the first commit with an empty xib. I've added a label and two images to the xib and now it doesn't animate on iOS 7. thanks.